# Upload file failure delivering result resultinfo

Tags: android, android-intent

When I read image from Gallery everything normal. But when I read image from file manager `( Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/HD-Wallpapers1.jpeg } )`, I got error.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);                   
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Picture"), 1);
```

**---onactivity result method---**

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);          
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**Error log**
08-14 10:29:44.376: E/AndroidRuntime(2063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {

dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/dHkGLr7F6v25DRUu7Vaq3GvXUW2c0gbxzs05WmmQ8GwMQAN5U8wb-LUJnTCt6IIYjww6gqJ9GT-ID_bxyjtRDdMav8DTnGhpxBV6KxKAEyjYBMsLvzkcv8M0OMfGwbn6yRnCAxdJZeFqi5BbbGzlTiTU_ukeAt0RbERJHdyAie-Dm7IuRg=w350-h350-nc.png }}

to activity {com.example.uploadtest/com.example.uploadtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: failure delivering result resultinfo

Answer (score 0):

To Add conditional should work:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
      //  Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
      //  imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);


   Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
   imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
   Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);          
   imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}
 }
```

Comment: check imagepath is null?

Comment: program break in :imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

Comment: selectedimage is  not null, it is: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/HD-Wallpapers1.jpeg

Comment: refer http://iswwwup.com/t/e0243b30f1b6/java-android-kitkat-failure-delivering-result-resultinfo.html